# css progress bar

Tags: mysql, css, progress-bar, progress

I have a question in regards to a progress bar. I've read pretty much all the posts here but it appears I can't make any of them work in my scenario.
I have the following which shows numbers such as 50/500 where 50 is the actual number and 500 is the max.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM db_ships WHERE ship_id = $user[ship_id] LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
print $db_field['shields'] . " / ";
print $db_field['max_shields'] . "";
```

Most progress bars that I see depict timeframes, I need to visually show the fraction

```
print $db_field['shields'] . " / ";
    print $db_field['max_shields'] . "";
```

How can I place this so I can have a progress bar depicting the progress?
I am sorry I am not good at css. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean? By the time CSS gets processed, you'd be at 100% already!

Comment: Do you want a prgress bar that shows 10% for the numbers you mentioned or do you want a progress bar for the query as such. If so, why? Every query that takes shorter than a second is considered a slow query. During 1 second the user won't have time to look at a progress bar, furthermore the progressbar would need to communicate with the process asynchronously otherwise you just get the response and you're on 100%.

Comment: i do not want a progress bar based on time. i need a visual bar to depict 50/500. based on the numbers stored on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<div class=\"progressbar_container\"><div class=\"progressbar\" style=\"width: ".($db_field['shields']/$db_field['max_shields']*100)."%\"></div></div>";
```

And define styles as needed. Maybe a border for the container and a background colour for the main bar. That's all there is to a basic progress bar.

Comment: my apologies, the above is just not displaying anything. am i missing something?

Comment: Try adding a `height` to the main progress bar.

Comment: Also, make sure you have styled `.progressbar_container` and `.progressbar` in your CSS file.

Comment: i made the .progressbar_container {background: white} and it is still not shwing.

Comment: could not help comment this - I did the same and had to put a &npsb; #&x0a; inside the block (div), in order to visualize content as background color ...

Comment: As I said, try adding `height:16px` to the `.progressbar`. `&nbsp;` should NEVER be used for layout.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way of doing it is placing a div inside a larger div and setting the percentage width of the inner div. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/nve2S/) showing what I mean.

You can get the percentage of `max_shields` by writing (Assuming they are both numbers)

```
$percentage = $db_field['shields'] * ($db_field['max_shields'] / 100);
```

Apply the percentage as the width of the inner div.

```
<div id="progress-inner" style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;"></div>
```

It would be a breeze to animate that progress bar using [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) if you wanted to.

Comment: Great! Leave a comment if there are any issues with the solution

Comment: $SQL = "SELECT * FROM db_ships WHERE ship_id = $user[ship_id] LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
print $db_field['shields'] . " / ";
print $db_field['max_shields'] . "";

$percentage = $db_field['shields'] * ($db_field['max_shields'] / 100);
<div id="progress-inner" style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;"></div>    ...... still not showing anything.

Comment: That's not what my answer said to write. Visit the fiddle I linked: http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/nve2S/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.table, th
{
background-color:Blue;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
<table class="table" >
        <tr id = "row1" >
            <td id ="cell1" class="td"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

    var i = 1;
    var timerID = 0;
    timerID = setTimeout("progress()",200); 
    var scell = '';
    var sbase = '';
    sbase = document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML;

function progress()
{

    var tend = "</tr></table>";
    var tstrt = "<table><tr>";
    scell = scell + "<td style='width:15;height:25' bgcolor=blue>";

    document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML = sbase + tstrt +  scell + tend; 


     if( i < 50) 
    {                    
        i = i + 1;

        timerID = setTimeout("progress()",200); 
    }
    else
     {
        if(timerID)
        {
   document.getElementById("cell1")
      .innerHTML=document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML 
      + "</tr></table>";
            clearTimeout(timerID);

        }
     }

  }
     </script>
```